# Connect to Local/On-premises Active Directory from PHP web application

Tags: php, active-directory, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

Seeking for guidance on the subject as I'm really stuck on this, I am trying to connect to a microsoft server over a network to login into my system by providing my microsoft credentials.

Now, what I want is whenever I try to hit my php application url, it will redirect me to microsoft login page and automatically authenticates with the microsoft credentials entered during system login and at the same time redirect back to my php application with the same credentials. I am using simplesaml in this case.

I tried using local AD as an IDP and simplesaml as an SP. When I am hitting my application url, it is redirecting me to my local AD login page but auto-login is not initiating with my microsoft credentials. I have to enter the microsoft credentials again. Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to federate simplesamlphp with ADFS.

You will then get an ADFS login page and if you have "Integrated Windows Auth" enabled you will get SSO so you won't have to login.

Comment: What did you specifically mean by enabling "Integrated Windows Auth"? Is it a part of ADFS configuration or browser setting?

Comment: Browser setting e.g. http://wiki.idera.com/display/Dashboard/Configuring+your+browser+for+Windows+Authentication