# Connect to On-premises Active Directory from PHP web application

Tags: php, active-directory, single-sign-on, adfs

Seeking for guidance on the subject as I'm really stuck on this, I am trying to connect to a microsoft server over a network to login into my system by providing my microsoft credentials.

Now, what I want is whenever I try to hit my php application url, it will redirect me to microsoft login page and automatically authenticates with the microsoft credentials entered during system login and at the same time redirect back to my php application with the same credentials. I am using simplesaml in this case.

I tried using local AD as an IDP and simplesaml as an SP. When I am hitting my application url, it is redirecting me to my local AD login page but auto-login is not initiating with my microsoft credentials. I have to enter the microsoft credentials again. Please help!!!

Comment: Might help if you show the related code

Comment: @WesleySmith This all based on adfs server and simplesaml configuration. No coding used. Coding will come only after successful redirection from local AD page to my php application to authenticate that user inside my application.

Comment: You've already asked a similar question that was closed - https://stackoverflow.com/q/64137776/9922. I gave you the answer there i.e. IWA.

Comment: This may also help - https://help.hcltechsw.com/domino/10.0.1/secu_enabling_iwa_adfs30.html

Comment: @rbrayb Integrated Is Windows Authentication setting to be enabled for both ADFS and browser?

Comment: If the browser you are using is in the -WIASupportedUserAgents list (and it usually is) then it's just a browser setting.